# How to multiple methods call every 5 minutes using Multi threading

Tags: c#, windows

I searched solution for this concept, i can't get a proper solution. Please help this below concept.

Having 3 methods, one method call every 5 minutes, second one call every 10 seconds, another one method is call every 1 hour. 
And please also need thread validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 3 different timers for this:

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer { Interval = 10000, Enabled = True };
Timer timer2 = new Timer { Interval = 300000, Enabled = True };
Timer timer3 = new Timer { Interval = 3600000, Enabled = True };

timer1.Tick += (s,e) => { Your code 10 Sec };
timer2.Tick += (s,e) => { Your code 5 Min };
timer3.Tick += (s,e) => { Your code 1 Hour };
```

or just one timer:

```
int repeat = 0;
Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = 10000, Enabled = True };
timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    //Do your 10 second code every time
    if(repeat%30==0)
    {
        //you every 5 minute code
    }
    if(repeat%360==0)
    {
        //you every 1 hour code
    }    
    repeat++;

}
```

Comment: Ashkan, Thank you very much. how to above code using without timer control and can you please provide brief code(with events), because i beginner of windows application.

Comment: @Krishna so you want a thread but without using a thread? also, the Tick event is shown right there..